# Spoj - EverLast - Need Hint

Tags: algorithm

I am trying to solve the SPOJ Problem EVERLAST, as given here,
[The fate of the Pineapple](http://www.spoj.com/problems/EVERLAST/)

Currently what I am trying is:

1) After the first season the population  = N * K
2) After the second season the population = N * K^2*(1-p)
since p is the probability that each pineapple is sterile and the initial N* K population dies out
3) After the third season the population = N * K^3 * (1-p)^2

a)The probability that pineapple population survives after second season =   (1- p^(N * K)), since it dies out completely with a probability p^(N * K)
b)Probability that pineapple population survives after third season = 1 - p^ (N* K^2 *(1-p)), since it dies out completely with a probability p^(N * K^2 * (1-p))
and so on..

so the probability of population surviving forever will be
(1-p^(N * K)) * (1-p^(N * K^2 * (1-p))) * .......

But I am getting the wrong answer, I cant find the hints to this anywhere.
Where am I going wrong in my approach? any hints please?

Comment: Someone please help!

Comment: Shouldn't there be a `floor()` in there somewhere? I assume fractions of pineapples aren't able to reproduce.

Comment: Yes. I haven't used floor, but converted the float value to integer, still the wrong output

Comment: Hope i get an answer soon.